# How do I create a user control with a pictureBox1 so I can use it later on any project?

Tags: c#, winforms

First I added many properties, but that's not the proper way to pass variables. How should I handle it?

Second, this control will be used like a `pictureBox1` in `form1 d`esigner (or any other form designer). And in form1, I used some events of the pictureBox1. Now I need to use the events of the `picturebox1` in the control, so do I need to create and use all the events in the Control code and not form1?

This is the user control code:

```
namespace Find_Distance
{
    public partial class pictureBox1Control : UserControl
    {

        public static PictureBox pb1;
        // blinking colors: yellow, red, yellow, transparent, repeat...
        public static Brush[] cloudColors = new[] { Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Transparent };
        // current color index
        public static int cloudColorIndex = 0;

        public pictureBox1Control()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pb1 = new PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox1 = pb1;
            SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |

            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        }

        private void pictureBox1Control_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1Control.pb1.Image, movingPoint);
            CloudEnteringAlert.Paint(e.Graphics, currentfactor, _distance);

            float distance = _kilometers / (float)1.09;//289617486; // One pixel distance is 1.09 kilometer.
            Pen p;
            p = new Pen(Brushes.Green);
            if (_points == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (Point pt in _pointsint)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, pt.X * (float)currentfactor, pt.Y * (float)currentfactor, 2f, 2f);
            }
            foreach (PointF pt in _movingpoints)
            {
                if (_Cloud == null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, (pt.X - distance) * (float)currentfactor, pt.Y * (float)currentfactor, 2f, 2f);
                }
            }
            foreach (PointF pt in _pointtocolor)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, pt.X * (float)currentfactor, pt.Y * (float)currentfactor, 2f, 2f);
            }
            if (_Cloud != null)
            {
                foreach (PointF pt in _Cloud)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(cloudColors[cloudColorIndex], pt.X * (float)currentfactor, pt.Y * (float)currentfactor, 2f, 2f);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var cloud in _clouds)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(
                   cloud.Brush, cloud.Center.X, cloud.Center.Y,
                   cloud.Diameter, cloud.Diameter);
            }
        }

        public static List<Ellipse> _clouds = new List<Ellipse>();
        public List<Ellipse> Clouds
        {
            get { return _clouds; }
        }

        public static List<PointF> _points = new List<PointF>();
        public List<PointF> Points
        {
            get { return _points; }
        }

        public static List<Point> _pointsint = new List<Point>();
        public List<Point> PointsInt
        {
            get { return _pointsint; }
        }

        public static List<PointF> _movingpoints = new List<PointF>();
        public List<PointF> MovingPoints
        {
            get { return _movingpoints; }
        }

        public static List<PointF> _pointtocolor = new List<PointF>();
        public List<PointF> PointtoColor
        {
            get { return _pointtocolor; }
        }

        public static List<PointF> _Cloud = new List<PointF>();
        public List<PointF> Cloud
        {
            get { return _Cloud; }
        }

        public static float _kilometers;
        public float Kilometers
        {
            get { return _kilometers; }
        }

        public static float _distance;
        public float Distance
        {
            get { return _distance; }
        }

        public static Point movingPoint;
        public static double currentfactor;
        public static float distance;
    }
}
```

On this user control designer, I added a pictureBox1.

And this is for example how I'm using it in Form1:

```
pictureBox1Control.pb1.Image = test.jpg;
```

But it dosen't show the image on the pictureBox1 in the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
pictureBox1Control.pb1.Image = test.jpg;
```

try using

```
pictureBox1Control.pb1.Load(@"c:\test.jpg");
```

Of course, make sure the file exists. Also, you should remove "static" from this line:

```
 public static PictureBox pb1;
```

If you have 10 windows opened, you might not want to display all the same image. I see that your PictureBox object is not added to the control. In the first method, after you create the PictureBox, use

```
this.Controls.Add(pb1)
```